# Microsoft Speech to Text Cognitive Service Close the session on EndOfStream in ContinuousRecognitionAsync

Tags: speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, speech-to-text

I'm testing the SpeechToText Cognitive Service of Microsoft in C# environment (Console App).

I'm using AudioConfig.FromStreamInput(), so I'm using Audio Stream as input and I start the recognizer in ContinuosRecognitionAsync mode.

All is working but:

Everytime recognition is done (Successfully), the recognizer fire a "Cancelled" event with "EndOfStream" reason and after I get the "SessionStopped" event.

In this way to recognize one other Utterance I need to Instantiate one other recognizer with ContinuousRecognitionAsync.

This behaviour I dont have if I'm using AugioConfig.FromDefaultMicrophoneInput() where session remain open between differents utterances until I'm using .StopContinuousRecognitionAsync().

Questions are:

- How I can keep session open between each "StreamInput" I pass to the recognizer (So similar to the Microphone input), so to don't restart recognizer every time.

Following the code I'm using:

To pass the stream I'm Using two classes:

```
public class EchoStream : MemoryStream
{
    private readonly ManualResetEvent _DataReady = new(false);
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> _Buffers = new();

    public bool DataAvailable { get { return !_Buffers.IsEmpty; } }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        _Buffers.Enqueue(buffer.Take(count).ToArray()); // add new data to buffer
        _DataReady.Set(); // allow waiting reader to proceed
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        _DataReady.WaitOne(); // block until there's something new to read

        if (!_Buffers.TryDequeue(out byte[] lBuffer)) // try to read
        {
            _DataReady.Reset();
            return -1;
        }

        if (!DataAvailable)
            _DataReady.Reset();

        Array.Copy(lBuffer, buffer, lBuffer.Length);
        return lBuffer.Length;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class VoiceAudioStream : PullAudioInputStreamCallback
{
    private readonly EchoStream _dataStream = new();
    private ManualResetEvent _waitForEmptyDataStream = null;

    public override int Read(byte[] dataBuffer, uint size)
    {
        if (_waitForEmptyDataStream != null && !_dataStream.DataAvailable)
        {
            _waitForEmptyDataStream.Set();
            return 0;
        }

        return _dataStream.Read(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
    }

    public void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        _dataStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override void Close()
    {
        if (_dataStream.DataAvailable)
        {
            _waitForEmptyDataStream = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            _waitForEmptyDataStream.WaitOne();
        }

        _waitForEmptyDataStream.Close();
        _dataStream.Dispose();
        base.Close();
    }
}
```

to start the recognizer i'm using following code:

```
private async void StartRegonition()
{
    try
    {
        if (!RecognitionIsRunning)
        {
            // We will continuously write incoming audio to shis stream.
            audioStream = new VoiceAudioStream();

            // Initialize with the format required by the Speech service
            var audioFormat = AudioStreamFormat.GetWaveFormatPCM(16000, 16, 1);
            // Configure speech SDK to work with the audio stream in right format.
            var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromStreamInput(audioStream, audioFormat);
            // Get credentials and region from client's message.
            var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(key, region);
            speechConfig.SpeechRecognitionLanguage = "it-IT";
            // With all the info at hand, finally create the SpeechRecognizer instance.
            speechClient = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

            stopRecognition = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

            speechClient.Recognized += (s, e) =>
            {
                IsRecognizing = false;
                sStop = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
                var seconds = sStop.TotalSeconds - sStart.TotalSeconds;
                Console.WriteLine($"Recognized: {e.Result.Text} - {seconds}");
            };
            
            speechClient.SessionStopped += async (s, e) =>
            {
                IsRecognizing = false;
                RecognitionIsRunning = false;
                await speechClient.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync();
                speechClient.Dispose();
                speechClient = null;
                audioStream.Dispose();
                audioStream = null;
                Console.WriteLine($"Session Id: {e.SessionId} Stopped!");
                if (!SystemStop)
                    StartRegonition();
            };


            // Finally start recognition on this particular client.
            await speechClient.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync();
            RecognitionIsRunning = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Continuous Recognition Started");

            Task.WaitAny(new[] { stopRecognition.Task });

            await StopRecognitionAsync();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Recognition Server Error: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

to write the Audio Stream I'm using following code:
(The source of Audio Bytes have a sample of 8000 Hz I need to resample to 16.000 with NAudio package)

```
        private void SendAudioStream(byte[] audioChunk)
        {
            try
            {
                if (audioStream is null)
                    throw new Exception("Audio Stream is not initialized!");
                if (!RecognitionIsRunning)
                    throw new Exception("Recognition is Stopped");

                using MemoryStream ms = new(audioChunk);
                var rs = new RawSourceWaveStream(ms, new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1));
                var outFormat = new WaveFormat(16000, rs.WaveFormat.Channels);
                using var resampler = new MediaFoundationResampler(rs, outFormat);
                using MemoryStream wms = new();
                WaveFileWriter.WriteWavFileToStream(wms, resampler);
                var reader = new BinaryReader(wms);
                byte[] readBytes;
                do
                {
                    readBytes = reader.ReadBytes(1024);
                    audioStream?.Write(readBytes, 0, readBytes.Length);
                } while (readBytes.Length > 0);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Send Audio Stream Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
```

Thank you for help

Piercarlo